# Why Visual Studio is using EqualityComparer when auto-generating Equals?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, equals

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017. When I create a class, in the quick actions menu, I can choose "***Generate Equals(object)***".

Let's say I have an `Account` class:

```
class Account
{
    public ushort? Id { get; private set; }
    public string Comments { get; private set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; private set; }
    public string Label { get; private set; }
    public Lawyer Lawyer { get; private set; }
}
```

the generated methods are:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return Equals(obj as Account);
}

public bool Equals(Account other)
{
    return other != null &&
            EqualityComparer<ushort?>.Default.Equals(Id, other.Id) &&
            Comments == other.Comments &&
            EqualityComparer<List<Contact>>.Default.Equals(Contacts, other.Contacts) &&
            Label == other.Label &&
            EqualityComparer<Lawyer>.Default.Equals(Lawyer, other.Lawyer);
}
```

For  `Comments` and `Label` Visual Studio uses `==`, while for `Id`, `List` and `Lawyer` it uses `EqualityComparer`.

My first thought was that `==` is used for value types while `EqualityComparer` is used for reference types. The problem is that `string` is not a value type (although used as one in equality context) and `ushort?` is not a reference type.

My second thought was that it is because `ushort?`, `List` and `Lawyer` accept `null`. The problem is that `string` accepts `null` as well.

So what is the rule? When it chooses `EqualityComparer` and when it uses a simple `==`? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `Nullable<T>` does not have `operator ==`, it does not implement `IEquatable<T>` interface and it has only `object.Equals(object other)` method. But direct calling of `object.Equals` for value types is unwanted.

Therefore, `EqualityComparer<ushort?>.Default.Equals` is used. It is implemented as:

```
internal class NullableEqualityComparer<T> : EqualityComparer<Nullable<T>> where T : struct, IEquatable<T>
{
    public override bool Equals(Nullable<T> x, Nullable<T> y) {
        if (x.HasValue) {
            if (y.HasValue) return x.value.Equals(y.value);
            return false;
        }
        if (y.HasValue) return false;
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If nullable types do not have operator `==`, why can I do this: `uint? a = 5; uint? b = 6; Console.WriteLine(a == b);`?

Comment: Because compiler specially treats nullable types and implements `operator ==` in place using corresponding operator for non-nullable types. Use ildasm to look how it is implemented.